# How would I convey a method with multiple parameters in a UML?

Tags: java

I created a UML for the following code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MP3Collection {    
// Instance field
private ArrayList<MP3> collection;
private int count;

public MP3Collection() {
    collection = new ArrayList<MP3>();
    count = 0;
}

public void addMP3(String artist, String song, String album, int trackLength) {
    //Creates an MP3 object
    MP3 MP3Addition = new MP3(artist, song, album, trackLength);
    //Places the MP3 object into the collection
    collection.add(MP3Addition);
    //Counts each MP3 added to the collection
    count++;
}

//Returns the total amount of MP3's added to the collection
public int getMP3Count() {
    return count;
}

//Returns the information for all MP3's
public String toString() {
    String MP3Information = "";
    MP3Information += "MP3 Collection\n";
    MP3Information += "Number Of MP3's In The Collection: " + count + "\n\n";
    MP3Information += "MP3 Informations:\n";

    for (MP3 MP3Addition : collection) {
        MP3Information += MP3Addition.toString() + "\n";
    }

    return MP3Information;
}
}
```

Here is my UML:

[image]

Did I pass the correct parameters for the `addMP3()` method? Also, I want sure how to depict the array instance in the second row of the diagram. So I would very much appreciate any explanations:) Please consider that today is my first time hearing about this topic.

Comment: Looks good to me. Note on terminology: you have an `ArrayList` instance variable, not an array. These are two very different things.

Comment: Noted, thank you very much!

Comment: the only thing I noticed is, in your constructor, `addMP3` and `getMP3Count`. perhaps you should change the variable `count` to `this.count` because `count` refers to local variable and what if your code will grow and you might add a local variable `count`.